# when should we add '&' and when we shouldn't while calling a function in c language?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

Program A

```
void create(struct Stack *st) 
{
    printf("Enter Size");
    scanf("%d",&st->size);
    st->top=-1;
    st->S=(int *)malloc(st->size*sizeof(int));
}

int main()
{
struct stack st;
create(&st);
return 0;
}
```

Program B - for program B assume that a linked list has been created with **first(declared as a global variable)** pointing at the 1st node in the list.

```
struct Node 
{ 
 int data;
 struct Node *next;
}*first=NULL;

void display(struct Node *p) 
{
while(p!=NULL)
{
 printf("%d ",p->data);
 p=p->next;
}
} 

int main()
{
display(first);
return 0;
}
```

My doubt is, why in program A while calling the **create** function, the **&** operator is required and why in program B it is not used while calling **display** function. Both create and display function take pointer as argument. Can you explain the relationship between & and * operator while calling a function with examples. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You use `&` when you have a variable and need to pass a pointer to that type of variable to the function. If you already have a pointer to the right type, you don’t use `&`.

Comment: `&x` allows to get the address of *x* whatever its usage, if you need to get the value of *x* use `x` if you need to get its address use `&x`

Comment: In the second program, the variable passed is *already* a pointer. It was defined as `*first`.

Comment: When you send some `&` as `arguments` to any function's `parameters`, there should be `*` to hold that `&`. This is the mere relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you send some `&` as `arguments` to any function's `parameters`, there should be `*` to hold that `&` or if there's any `*` in function's `parameters` you can send `arguments` like `&` or `*`. This is the mere relationship.

In **Program A:**

```
void create(struct Stack *st) 
{
    printf("Enter Size");
    scanf("%d",&st->size);
    st->top=-1;
    st->S=(int *)malloc(st->size*sizeof(int));
}

int main()
{
struct stack st;
create(&st);
return 0;
```

You need to send `&st` because sending `&st` to `create()` provides you the access to the memory where `st` is stored. If you send `st`--which is just a name of the memory location, where `st`'s data is stored--as an argument to `create()` that would be merely copying the `st` into `struct Stack *st` and result into an error. And you cannot modify the original value using its copy as in the case of `scanf("%d", &st->size);` that's why in the first program you need to send the address of `st`.

In **Program B:**

```
struct Node 
{ 
 int data;
 struct Node *next;
}*first=NULL;

void display(struct Node *p) 
{
while(p!=NULL)
{
 printf("%d ",p->data);
 p=p->next;
}
} 

int main()
{
display(first);
return 0;
}
```

You have already the memory address where `data` of `struct Node` type is stored, i.e. the value of `first`. That's why you don't need to do `display(&first)` in this case just make a copy of `first` and use it in `display()` function.

> Can you explain the relationship between & and * operator while calling a function with examples.

But you can also do `display(&first)` in **Program B** like this:

```
struct Node 
{ 
 int data;
 struct Node *next;
}*first=NULL;

void display(struct Node **p) 
{
while(*p!=NULL)
{
 printf("%d ",(*p)->data);
 *p=(*p)->next;
}
} 

int main()
{
display(&first);
return 0;
}
```

and I hope the example given above makes it clear when to use `*` and `&` while calling any function, according to its parameters. Beware, `display`ing data using `&first` would modify the address of `first` in `*p=(*p)->next;` and your `head` pointer to the linked list will be lost so, this example is just for demonstration purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Whatever the type of *x* `&x` allows to get the address of *x* whatever the goal. If you need to get the value of *x* use `x` if you need to get its address use `&x`

In the first program to give the address of *st* allows *create* to modify it, so in *main* back from *create* the variable *st* is modified.

But having :

```
void create(struct Stack st) 
{
    printf("Enter Size");
    scanf("%d",&st.size);
    st.top=-1;
    st.S=(int *)malloc(st.size*sizeof(int));
}

int main()
{
  struct stack st;
  create(st);
  return 0;
}
```

in that case *create* works on a *copy* of *st* from *main* and back to *main* there is no change in *st*

When doing

> ```
> scanf("%d",&st->size);
> ```

the goal is to read an `int` and to memorize it in the field *size*, for that it is needed to give the address of that field, so `&st->size`rather than `st->size` which gives its value

---

In the second program *first* is already a pointer, this is why the call in *main* is `display(first);` rather than `display(&first);`, anyway notice *first* valuing NULL *display* does nothing because `(p!=NULL)`is immediately false

Of course you can also get the address of *first* with `&first` but in that case you get a `struct Node **` so supposing `display(&first);` *display* must be changed to `void display(struct Node ** p)` and of course its body must be adapted

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change an original object in a function instead of its copy you have to pass it by reference. Passing by reference in C means passing an object indirectly through a pointer to the object.

For example if in the first program you will write

```
void create(struct Stack st) 
{
    printf("Enter Size");
    scanf("%d",&st.size);
    st.top=-1;
    st.S=(int *)malloc(st.size*sizeof(int));
}

int main()
{
struct stack st;
create(st);
return 0;
}
```

then the function will deal with a copy of the object st passed to the function. Changing the copy  has no effect on the original object.

In the second program

```
struct Node 
{ 
 int data;
 struct Node *next;
}*first=NULL;

void display(struct Node *p) 
{
while(p!=NULL)
{
 printf("%d ",p->data);
 p=p->next;
}
} 

int main()
{
display(first);
return 0;
}
```

the function `display` deals with a copy of the pointer `first`. The pointer itself is not being changed in the function. So there is no sense to pass it by reference. On the other hand, a node pointed to by the pointer is passed by reference. So the compiler does not create a copy of an object of the type struct Node. You could change the pointed node in the function if it was required.

Comment: Yeah, I got it.